# intervals with equal density sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

A have a table with traders statistics:

```
id  |  number of trades   |  profit
1   |  10                 | 1.05
2   |  20                 | 1.06
3   |  1000               | 1.06
4   |  100                | 0.95
5   |  150                | 1.06
6   |  20                 | 1.06
7   |  20                 | 1.07
...
```

I want to build table with **100 intervals** by number of trades and each interval should have equal number of traders:

```
 number of trades   |   number of traders    |   average profit
 0-156              |   1500                 |   1.05
 156-1500           |   1500                 |   0.95
 1500-1610          |   1500                 |   1.55
 ....
```

What would the query look like?

Comment: Can you elaborate? It's not clear.

Comment: I want to split all traders in 100 untervals with equal number of traders in each and then count average profit for each interval.
Traders in each interval should be close to each other by number of trades.

Comment: Does `id` column in the table signify trader id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the below query. Hope this solves the problem.

```
SELECT  MIN(number_of_trades)::text || '-' || MAX(number_of_trades)::text AS "number of trades" 
, COUNT(number_of_trades) AS "number of traders"
, AVG(number_of_trades*profit) AS AvgProfit 
FROM 
(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY number_of_trades) AS rn
     , number_of_trades
     , profit 
     , (COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY NULL) / 100) AS Grp
   FROM TradersStat
  ) tab
GROUP BY (rn - 1) / Grp
```

Here you can see it working: [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/141a5/48)

Solution assumes that the count of records is atleast 100.

Algorithm is as follows:

1. Number the traders in increasing order of number_of_trades.
2. Divide the resultset into 100 chunks and do number crunching on each chuck.

[EDIT]

`COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY NULL)` counts total number of traders. When we divide this with 100 what we get is number of traders in each group. `PARTITION BY` in general, dictates by which column(s) a dataset needs to partitioned and `COUNT(*)` counts the number of records in each partition.   `PARTITION BY NULL` does the trick of treating all the records in the dataset as a single partition and so `COUNT(*)` on it, basically is counting all records in the dataset. We could not have used COUNT(*) without `OVER()` clause as `COUNT(*)` is an aggregate function and the usage would have been invalid.

Comment: right, because the sample contains records less than 100. Try this query with your input dataset.

Comment: can you pls explain what does this row:  (COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY NULL) / 100) AS Grp

Comment: gr8..see the edit. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: I dont understand what is OVER(PARTITION BY NULL)

Comment: see edit. Google with OVER() in SQL, you would get a better understanding

Answer (score 1):

1. Break the problem down into smaller parts.
   see Polya  How to Solve It
2. Group by Interval  (centile for 100 intervals).
   (just don't display the Interval number in your output)

   ```
   Select
      Interval,
      Min(NumOfTrades) as minTrades,
      Max(NumOfTrades) as maxTrades,
      Count(*) as NumOfTraders,
      Avg(profit) as AvgProfit
   From
      ... and some magic here, see below ...
   Group by Interval
   ```
3. Create Intervals

   ```
   (Select 
        SeqByTradesAndID / 100 as Interval,
        id,
        NumOfTrades,
        profit
    From
        ... again, some inner workings ...
    )
   ```
4. Sequence number by ascending Trades AND ID

   ```
       (Select
            (Select Count(*) From Traders as T2
             Where ( T2.NumOfTrades < T1.NumOfTrades )
             Or    ( T2.NumOfTrades = T1.NumOfTrades 
                 And T2.id          < T1.id)
            ) as SeqByTradesAndID,
            T1.id,
            T1.NumOfTrades,
            T1.profit
         From Traders as T1
   ```

I think that this should do it, but I haven't tested it.